# Table decleration

Tags: tables, grouping

In my document, I have a table, I want to use `\setlength{\tabcolsep}{18pt}` but since there is one more table, this also affects the other, which I don't want to change. Therefore I thought of creating another ".tex" file which has only 1 table and then including it in the main file, but this didn't work. What can I do? Actually, my main purpose is to expand the table to the column width without changing the font size.

```
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{18pt}
\begin{tabular}{|cc|cc|}
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\textbf{Orbital positions}}     & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{Total solar irradiance}}        \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{Earth}} & \textbf{Moon} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{near side}} & \textbf{far side} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{perihelion} & perigee & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{1,401.65} & 1,415.54 \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{perihelion} & apogee  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{1,400.83} & 1,416.36 \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{aphelion}   & perigee & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{1,311.18} & 1,323.74 \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{aphelion}   & apogee  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{1,310.44} & 1,324.49 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
```

Additionally I didn't write `\begin{table}` because when I write it that the font-type was changing.

Comment: Make your declaration local. FOr example, if it is in `table` float, put it after `\begin{table}` . BTW, any float doesn't change fonts. For further help, please extend your code fragment to complete small document, which reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To limit the scope of the `\setlength{\tabcolsep}{18pt}` instruction to a single `tabular` environment, I suggest you place a `\begingroup` instruction immediately before `\setlength{\tabcolsep}{18pt}` and an `\endgroup instruction immediately after` \end{tabular}`.

Assuming you really need vertical rules in the `tabular` environment, I would further like to suggest that you replace `\begin{tabular}{|cc|cc|}` with `\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}`, as doing so will let you get rid of ten `\multicolumn{1}{...}{...}` wrappers and significantly cut down on code clutter.

If your goal is for the four-column table to occupy the full width of the current column and if you're ok with the four columns having equal widths, I suggest you employ a `tabularx` environment and set its target width to `\columnwith`. No need to experiment around with various trial values of `\tabcolsep`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} 

\usepackage{tabularx} % for 'tabularx' env. and 'X' col. type
% Define a centered version of 'X' column type:
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\begin{document}

% Limit scope of '\setlength' instruction to current TeX group:
\begingroup 
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{18pt}
\noindent
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\textbf{Orbital positions}} & 
\multicolumn{2}{ c|}{\textbf{Total solar irradiance}} \\ \hline
\textbf{Earth} & \textbf{Moon} & 
\textbf{near side} & \textbf{far side} \\ \hline
perihelion & perigee & 1,401.65 & 1,415.54 \\ \hline
perihelion & apogee  & 1,400.83 & 1,416.36 \\ \hline
aphelion   & perigee & 1,311.18 & 1,323.74 \\ \hline
aphelion   & apogee  & 1,310.44 & 1,324.49 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\endgroup


\bigskip\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{|C|C|C|C|}
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\textbf{Orbital positions}} & 
\multicolumn{2}{ c|}{\textbf{Total solar irradiance}} \\ \hline
\textbf{Earth} & \textbf{Moon} & 
\textbf{near side} & \textbf{far side} \\ \hline
perihelion & perigee & 1,401.65 & 1,415.54 \\ \hline
perihelion & apogee  & 1,400.83 & 1,416.36 \\ \hline
aphelion   & perigee & 1,311.18 & 1,323.74 \\ \hline
aphelion   & apogee  & 1,310.44 & 1,324.49 \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The one with tabularx is nice, but is there way to write to that table.

Comment: @BarbarosTeoman - Please clarify what you mean by "write to that table".

Comment: I forgot to write caption, how can I add captions? \caption doesn't work

Comment: You're still not willing to use a `table` envrionment, right? If that's the case, I suggest you load the caption package and use a `\captionof{table}{...}` directive to create a caption string.

Answer (score 3):

It is not clear, why you like to increase `\tabcolsep`. I would rather define width of columns, for example by employ `array` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
\begin{tabular}{|*4{w{c}{6em}|}}
    \hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\textbf{Orbital positions}}     
                & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{Total solar irradiance}}      \\  \hline
\textbf{Earth}  & \textbf{Moon} & \textbf{near side}    & \textbf{far side} \\  \hline
perihelion      & perigee       & 1,401.65              & 1,415.54          \\  \hline
perihelion      & apogee        & 1,400.83              & 1,416.36          \\  \hline
aphelion        & perigee       & 1,311.18              & 1,323.74          \\  \hline
aphelion        & apogee        & 1,310.44              & 1,324.49          \\ \hline
\end{tabular}    
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Note:**  inserting table in the float for sure not change fonts used in table.

Answer (score 2):

With `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{cccc}[hvlines,columns-width=6em]
\RowStyle[nb-rows=2]{\bfseries}
\Block{1-2}{Orbital positions} & & 
\Block{1-2}{Total solar irradiance} \\ 
Earth      & Moon    & near side & far side \\ 
perihelion & perigee & 1,401.65  & 1,415.54 \\ 
perihelion & apogee  & 1,400.83  & 1,416.36 \\ 
aphelion   & perigee & 1,311.18  & 1,323.74 \\ 
aphelion   & apogee  & 1,310.44  & 1,324.49 \\ 
\end{NiceTabular}    

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

Answer (score 1):

It is very easy to achieve what you want using `tabularray` package:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}
Some text only to show the table has the width of the text line.
It is very easy to achieve what you want using \texttt{tabularray} package:
\begin{center}
\captionof{table}{My caption}
\begin{tblr}{colspec={*4{X[c]}},
    hlines, vlines,
    row{1-2}={font=\bfseries},
    }
\SetCell[c=2]{c}Orbital positions & &
\SetCell[c=2]{c}Total solar irradiance & \\ 
Earth & Moon & near side & far side \\ 
perihelion & perigee & 1,401.65 & 1,415.54 \\ 
perihelion & apogee  & 1,400.83 & 1,416.36 \\ 
aphelion   & perigee & 1,311.18 & 1,323.74 \\ 
aphelion   & apogee  & 1,310.44 & 1,324.49 \\ 
\end{tblr}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]